# Fixing xfs fs error lives on home directory

Tags: debian, filesystems, xfs

How to fix xfs fs error on home directory as unmount it will get denied/prevented ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot and add `1` or `systemd.unit=rescue.target` or `systemd.unit=emergency.target` as GRUB kernel parameter
2. Run `mount | grep /home` to find out what your home partition is. If it's not mounted, run `blkid` and check your `cat /etc/fstab` for the same entry.
3. Run `sudo unmount /dev/sdXY` or `sudo mount -o remount,ro /dev/sdXY` from above
4. Run `sudo xfs_repair /dev/sdXY`
5. Reboot

Comment: I'm sorry but indeed I'm blind 1st:Reboot and add 1 or systemd.unit=rescue.target or systemd.unit=emergency.target as GRUB kernel parameter
???

Comment: Any one of them should work.